# Is there a way to create an alias of an enum value?

Tags: enums, rust, alias

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
enum MyType {
    Left,
    Right,

    #[cfg(universe = "normal")]
    Port = Left,
    #[cfg(universe = "normal")]
    Starboard = Right,

    #[cfg(universe = "mirror")]
    Port = Right,
    #[cfg(universe = "mirror")]
    Starboard = Left,

}
```

If you actually try it, you get this error (I had to add `MyType::`):

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
 --> <anon>:9:12
  |
9 |     Port = MyType::Left,
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ unimplemented constant expression: enum variants
```

[Here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/93e70ecb7fbe05caa74dfb2bf3c29315edc2b3e6/src/librustc_const_eval/eval.rs#L681) is where that error is triggered.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an associated constant to get a constant that looks very similar to an enum variant:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum X {
    A,
    B,
}

impl X {
    pub const A1: X = X::A;
}
```

The associated constant is namespaced inside the enum, just like normal variants. It is compatible with pattern matching — even the unreachable warning and exhaustive matching rules work.

```
match x {
    X::A1 => ...,
    X::B => ...,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eb364d9da2c5470e3c72794116dbff7a&version=stable)

There are some limitations: most importantly you can't have any data associated with that value. You also need to `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]` on your struct.

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know.

Enums in Rust are not "bundle of constant values" like they are in C. There is support for associating a numeric value to the constants, but that's it. Of course, you could create constants of any name, but they would not allow you to pattern match an enum value.

In a sense, an alias on a enum variant is a bit like an alias on a type field. I've never seen any occurrence of a single field identified by two names; I wonder if there's any language that supports it.

---

The solution I would propose it to bite the bullet and create two separate enums with a conversion between them:

```
use std::convert::From;

enum Side {
    Left,
    Right,
}

enum PortSide {
    Port,
    Starboard,
}

#[cfg(not(universe = "mirror"))]
impl From<Side> for PortSide {
    fn from(s: Side) -> PortSide {
        match s {
            Side::Left => PortSide::Port,
            Side::Right => PortSide::Starboard,
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(universe = "mirror")]
impl From<Side> for PortSide {
    fn from(s: Side) -> PortSide {
        match s {
            Side::Left => PortSide::Starboard,
            Side::Right => PortSide::Port,
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'd advise you to not require a feature to be specified, but instead allow a default behavior in the absence of this feature. In your case, "normal" seems like it should be the default behavior.

Comment: I was thinking about recommending a secondary enum. It seems like there are times where you'd want one representation or the other, but not both concurrently.

Comment: C "supports" enum and struct field aliases using through preprocessor. I'm only half-joking here - the classic Unix implementations of e.g. `struct stat` use this feature *a lot*, and it is part of the reason why struct and union fields are prefixed (the other part being that it protects the standard library from *application* #defining something that happens to match a struct field).

Answer (score -3):

Your implementation doesn't make any sense. Look at a simpler version:

```
enum MyType {
    One,
    Two = One,
}
```

Said another way:

```
enum MyType {
    One = 1,
    Two = 1,
}
```

You are asking the compiler to create two enum variants that are the same, but the whole point of enums is that they are *exclusive* of each other.

Instead, create a constant (associated or otherwise):

```
enum MyType {
    One,
}

const TWO: MyType = MyType::One;
```

Comment: Yes I'm trying to create aliases. Rust already has type aliases with no problems. Can you given an example of a way that supporting enum variant aliases would break something because I can't see any.

Comment: @Timmmm: The problem is pattern matching. Which arm is taken in case you have `match x { One => {}, Two => {} }`?

Comment: That's not a problem. It would behave exactly as if you wrote `match x { One => {}, One => {} }`, i.e. print an error. (The error it actually prints is `This is an unreachable pattern`.)